# Usage of Database.getQueryLocator

Tags: soql, batch, governorlimits

I am new to the batch class working, and I have a somewhat weird question. When I write this in the `start` method of a batch class:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
         SELECT Id, DocumentNumber__c, Segment__c
         FROM Account
         WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName IN :Constants.RECORD_TYPE
         AND Id IN :accountIds]);
```

Is it different from `return Database.getQueryLocator(query);`
where `query` is the SOQL I had written above?

Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are the same thing.

```
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

and

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
```

are identical.

It is preferable to use the second one using a static query, as the query syntax will be checked when you save the Apex class.

Comment: both will return more than 50,000 records if taken in batch class context ??

Comment: yes, that is right